# Intellij Turning Characters into actual Symbols

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I noticed with the new IntelliJ update, that it turns symbols like >= into the actual math greater than or equal to sign, along with arrows (->) and things like that. How do i turn this feature off and just get the raw characters.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Much nicer with the ligatures, though.

Comment: that is true, it does look cleaner, I personally don't like them though :/

Comment: ligature vs no-ligature is going to be another one of those never-ending battles, after spaces vs tabs, and whether to put "{" on a new line... :D

Comment: haha i feel like i'm in the minority of those who put the { on a new line instead of the same line

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like whatever font you are using supports [ligatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_ligature), and IntelliJ is set to render them too.

To change the settings, first go to "File > Settings" and then select "Editor > Font" tab:

[image]

Either:

- select a font that doesn't have ligatures, or;
- uncheck "Enable font ligatures"

Comment: Yikes. Why in the world would an IDE allow them even as an option?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Personally, I like them a lot :)

Comment: Madness. Pure madness. Next will be K&R style, and then... *vi keybindings*.